# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: setProperty must be overridden by all subclasses of SOAPMessage at

Tags: java, jboss5.x

I have a problem. Here is my stacktrace:

> javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: setProperty must be overridden by all subclasses of SOAPMessage at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.Ejb3TxPolicy.handleExceptionInOurTx(Ejb3TxPolicy.java:77) at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:83) at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:190) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.security.RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptorv2.invoke(RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptorv2.java:201) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:186) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.stateful.StatefulContainer.dynamicInvoke(StatefulContainer.java:571) at org.jboss.ejb3.session.InvokableContextClassProxyHack._dynamicInvoke(InvokableContextClassProxyHack.java:53) at org.jboss.aop.Dispatcher.invoke(Dispatcher.java:91) at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.invoke(AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.java:82) at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:891) at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.completeInvocation(ServerThread.java:744) at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:697) at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:524) at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:232) Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: setProperty must be overridden by all subclasses of SOAPMessage at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.handleRemoteException(ClientImpl.java:396) at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:302) at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:170) at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:150) at $Proxy324.zaduzi(Unknown Source) at agencija.Pretrazivac.rezervisi(Pretrazivac.java:159) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111) at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.java:69) at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:73) at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:59) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:72) at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_11068088.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_11068088.java) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:88) at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_11068088.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_11068088.java) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.ExtendedPersistenceContextPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ExtendedPersistenceContextPropagationInterceptor.java:60) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.stateful.StatefulInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatefulInstanceInterceptor.java:81) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:79) at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:190) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.security.RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptorv2.invoke(RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptorv2.java:201) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:186) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.stateful.StatefulContainer.dynamicInvoke(StatefulContainer.java:571) at org.jboss.ejb3.session.InvokableContextClassProxyHack._dynamicInvoke(InvokableContextClassProxyHack.java:53) at org.jboss.aop.Dispatcher.invoke(Dispatcher.java:91) at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.invoke(AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.java:82) at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:891) at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.completeInvocation(ServerThread.java:744) at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:697) at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:524) at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:232) at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:211) at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1724) at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:629) at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:60) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:61) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.security.client.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:65) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:74) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.PojiProxy.invoke(PojiProxy.java:62) at $Proxy3.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:207) at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:164) at $Proxy2.rezervisi(Unknown Source) at Testiranje.Test.main(Test.java:64) at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:72) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:61) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.security.client.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:65) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:74) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.PojiProxy.invoke(PojiProxy.java:62) at $Proxy3.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:207) at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:164) at $Proxy2.rezervisi(Unknown Source) at Testiranje.Test.main(Test.java:64) Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: setProperty must be overridden by all subclasses of SOAPMessage at javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage.setProperty(Unknown Source) at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPMessageImpl.(SOAPMessageImpl.java:87) at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:169) at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonSOAP11Binding.createMessage(CommonSOAP11Binding.java:57) at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonSOAPBinding.bindRequestMessage(CommonSOAPBinding.java:157) at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient.invoke(CommonClient.java:290) at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:290) at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:170) at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:150) at $Proxy324.zaduzi(Unknown Source) at agencija.Pretrazivac.rezervisi(Pretrazivac.java:159) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111) at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.java:69) at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:73) at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:59) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:72) at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_11068088.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_11068088.java) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:88) at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_11068088.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_11068088.java) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.ExtendedPersistenceContextPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ExtendedPersistenceContextPropagationInterceptor.java:60) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.stateful.StatefulInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatefulInstanceInterceptor.java:81) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:79) at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:190) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.security.RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptorv2.invoke(RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptorv2.java:201) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:186) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67) at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) at org.jboss.ejb3.stateful.StatefulContainer.dynamicInvoke(StatefulContainer.java:571) at org.jboss.ejb3.session.InvokableContextClassProxyHack._dynamicInvoke(InvokableContextClassProxyHack.java:53) at org.jboss.aop.Dispatcher.invoke(Dispatcher.java:91) at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.invoke(AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.java:82) at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:891) at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.completeInvocation(ServerThread.java:744) at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:697) at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:524) at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:232)

```
JBoss jboss-5.1.0.GA JDK 1.6.0_25
```

I've tried many thigs that I found here but they didn't work. I realy need help, so I'll be grateful if someone have advices or maybe solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you (or someone) subclassed `SOAPMessage` but didn't override a method `setProperty` that must be overridden.  Then that not-fully implemented subclass was used, causing a runtime exception.

Another possibility is that you are trying to use a `SOAPMessage` instance instead of using a subclass of `SOAPMessage`.  `SOAPMessage` classes purposefully throw exceptions as they are not intended to be used directly.  The intent is to subclass a `SOAPMessage` and implement the "data" part of the message yourself.

Odds are you can't fix this without specifying a fully-implemented SOAPMessage, or fixing the one that (maybe) is under development.

Comment: I didn't use SOAPMessage in any of my classes. I get this exception when I call three methods from my Test class using JNDI(but when I call some other method from same class it works). These methods which I call just call some other methods from different package(methods works with database) and when I separately tested these methods they works. I tried to explain but it's a bit confuseing, sorry :)